# How to calculate a number of minutes per 12/24h with discontinous value

Tags: javascript

As you can see in my snippet, I have two array.
So that you can understand better, this is patient data (fake).

- The first Array `patientUnderVNI`  represents they day patient is
  under non invasive ventilation.
- The second Array `patientVentValues`  represents an array of device
  data that sends ventilation data for this patient every x minutes on several days
  (usually every minutes but device disconnections can happen)

The issue is I want to know for each **VNI** day (entry for this day is present in the first array) the number of minutes of ventilation for the last 24hours since last vent value of the day.

I was thinking I just need to substract last patientVentValues datetime of day minus the first value 24h ago. But It can happens that ventilation is started and then stopped several times during the day. The issue is I don't know when device is connected or disconnected

You can see that in my example on 2014-01-01 : Patient is ventilated during 6min the morning and then 4 minutes the afternoon = 10 min `(for timerange 2014-10-31 16:57:03.13 -> 2014-11-01 16:57:03.13 )`

So then I thought maybe the best is to calculate the average interval in seconds on the whole `patientVentValues` array and group by the interval the most common (here it would be something like ~ 70s)
and then count the number of lines per day multiplied by this interval 
For 2014/11/01 it would be  11 lines * 70 s = 770 seconds
or 770/60 =  ~ 13 min

**It's ok if it's not the exact value.**

Can you help me generate the output I showed in the snippet ?

Sorry I tried to be as clear as possible

```js
const patientUnderVNI = [
    {"datetime":"2014-11-01 06:53:03.13"},
    {"datetime":"2014-11-03 06:53:03.13"}
];

const p_table = [
{datetime:"2014-11-01 07:03:03"},
{datetime:"2014-11-01 07:04:03"},
{datetime:"2014-11-01 07:05:03"},
{datetime:"2014-11-01 07:06:03"},
{datetime:"2014-11-01 07:07:03"},
{datetime:"2014-11-01 07:08:03"},
    {datetime:"2014-11-02 10:55:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 10:56:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 10:57:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 10:58:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 10:59:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:00:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:01:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:02:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:03:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:04:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:05:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:06:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:07:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:08:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:09:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:10:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:11:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:12:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:13:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:14:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:15:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:16:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:17:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:18:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:19:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:20:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:21:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:22:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:23:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:24:11"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:25:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:26:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:27:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:28:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:29:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:30:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:31:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:32:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:33:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:34:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:35:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:36:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:37:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:38:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:39:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:40:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:41:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:42:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:43:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:44:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:45:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:46:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:47:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:48:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:49:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:50:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:51:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:52:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:53:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:54:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:55:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:56:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:57:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:58:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 11:59:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:00:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:01:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:02:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:03:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:04:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:05:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:06:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:07:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:08:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:09:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:10:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:11:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:12:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:13:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:14:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:15:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:16:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:17:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:18:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:19:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:20:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:21:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:22:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:23:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:24:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:25:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:26:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:27:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:28:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:29:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:30:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:31:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:32:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:33:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:34:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:35:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:36:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:37:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:38:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:39:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:40:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:41:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:42:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:43:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:44:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:45:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:46:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:47:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:48:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:49:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:50:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:51:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:52:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:53:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:54:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:55:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:56:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:57:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:58:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 12:59:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:00:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:01:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:02:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:03:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:04:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:05:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:06:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:07:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:08:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:09:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:10:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:11:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:12:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:13:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:14:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:15:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:16:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:17:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:18:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:19:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:20:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:21:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:22:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:23:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:24:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:25:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:26:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:27:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:28:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:29:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:30:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:31:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:32:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:33:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:34:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:35:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:36:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:37:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:38:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:39:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:40:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:41:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:42:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:43:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:44:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:45:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:46:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:47:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:48:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:49:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:50:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:51:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:52:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:53:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:54:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:55:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:56:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:57:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:58:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 13:59:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:00:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:01:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:02:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:03:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:04:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:05:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:06:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:07:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:08:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:09:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:10:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:11:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:12:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:13:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:14:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:15:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:16:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:17:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:18:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:19:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:20:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:21:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:22:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:23:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:24:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:25:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:26:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:27:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:28:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:29:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:30:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:31:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:32:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:33:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:34:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:35:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:36:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:37:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:38:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:39:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:40:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:41:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:42:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:43:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:44:12"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:45:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:46:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:47:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:48:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:49:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:50:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:51:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:52:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:53:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:54:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:55:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:56:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:57:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:58:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 14:59:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:00:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:01:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:02:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:03:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:04:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:05:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:06:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:07:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:08:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:09:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:10:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:11:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:12:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:13:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:14:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:15:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:16:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:17:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:18:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:19:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:20:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:21:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:22:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:23:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:24:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:25:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:26:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:27:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:28:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:29:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:30:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:31:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:32:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:33:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:34:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:35:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:36:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:37:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:38:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:39:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:40:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:41:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:42:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:43:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:44:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:45:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:46:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:47:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:48:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:49:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:50:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:51:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:52:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:53:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:54:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:55:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:56:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:57:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:58:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 15:59:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:00:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:01:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:02:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:03:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:04:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:05:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:06:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:07:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:08:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:09:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:10:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:11:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:12:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:13:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:14:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:15:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:16:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:17:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:18:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:19:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:20:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:21:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:22:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:23:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:24:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:25:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:26:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:27:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:28:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:29:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:30:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:31:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:32:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:33:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:34:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:35:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:36:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:37:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:38:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:39:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:40:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:41:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:42:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:43:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:44:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:45:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:46:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:47:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:48:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:49:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:50:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:51:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:52:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:53:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:54:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:55:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:56:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:57:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:58:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 16:59:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:00:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:01:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:02:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:03:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:04:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:05:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:06:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:07:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:08:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:09:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:10:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:11:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:12:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:13:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:14:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:15:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:16:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:17:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:18:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:19:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:20:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:21:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:22:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:23:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:24:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:25:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:26:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:27:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:28:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:29:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:30:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:31:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:32:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:33:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:34:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:35:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:36:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:37:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:38:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:39:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:40:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:41:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:42:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:43:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:44:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:45:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:46:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:47:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:48:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:49:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:50:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:51:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:52:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:53:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:54:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:55:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:56:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:57:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:58:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 17:59:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:00:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:01:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:02:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:03:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:04:13"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:05:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:06:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:07:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:08:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:09:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:10:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:11:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:12:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:13:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:14:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:15:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:16:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:17:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:18:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:19:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:20:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:21:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:22:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:23:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:24:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:25:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:26:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:27:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:28:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:29:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:30:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:31:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:32:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:33:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:34:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:35:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:36:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:37:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:38:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:39:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:40:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:41:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:42:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:43:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:44:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:45:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:46:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:47:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:48:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:49:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:50:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:51:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:52:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:53:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:54:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:55:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:56:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:57:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:58:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 18:59:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:00:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:01:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:02:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:03:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:04:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:05:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:06:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:07:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:08:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:09:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:10:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:11:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:12:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:13:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:14:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:15:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:16:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:17:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:18:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:19:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:20:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:21:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:22:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:23:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:24:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:25:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:26:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:27:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:28:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:29:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:30:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:31:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:32:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:33:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:34:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:35:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:36:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:37:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:38:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:39:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:40:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:41:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:42:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:43:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:44:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:45:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:46:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:47:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:48:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:49:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:50:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:51:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:52:14"},
{datetime:"2014-11-02 19:53:14"}
];


// WIP
var helper = {};

// Count each time an interval occur in values
for (var i = 1; i < p_table.length; i++) {
  var d1 = new Date(p_table[i].datetime);
  var d2 = new Date(p_table[i - 1].datetime)
  var curr_interval_millis = d1 - d2;
  var curr_interval_seconds = curr_interval_millis / 1000;
  var key = Math.floor(curr_interval_seconds / 10) * 10; // We group by dozen of seconds and then put it back
  if (!helper[key]) helper[key] = 1;
  else helper[key] += 1;
}

console.log("Count each time an interval occur in values")
console.log(helper);

// Get the interval that occur the most often
// Is this doable in the array above ?
var maxKey = -1;
var maxCount = 0;
Object.keys(helper).forEach(key => {
  var currMaxCount = helper[key];
  if (currMaxCount > maxCount) {
    maxKey = key;
    maxCount = currMaxCount;
  }
});

console.log("max", maxKey, helper[maxKey])
var interval = maxKey;
// multiply this interval with the number of lines to have approximate monitoring time per 24h /12h
// for each line - 24h then get number of lines and multiply by interval (/60 to get minute)
// Count number of line per day

var tmp = [];
var aGLLD1219Detected = [];

// On essaye dans le sens inverse pour améliorer la performance en imaginant que les dernieres valeurs ont peut etre directement un acte
for(var i = p_table.length -1 ; i >=0  ; i--) {

  var d1 = new Date(p_table[i].datetime);  
  var d1min24H = new Date(p_table[i].datetime);
  var d1min12H = new Date(p_table[i].datetime);
  d1min24H.setHours(d1min24H.getHours() - 24);
  d1min12H.setHours(d1min24H.getHours() - 12);
  //console.log(d1min24H,d1);
  var last24hArr = p_table.filter( e => (new Date(e.datetime) > d1min24H && new Date(e.datetime) <= d1));
  var last12hArr = p_table.filter( e => (new Date(e.datetime) > d1min12H && new Date(e.datetime) <= d1));
//console.log("nb line last24: " + last24hArr.length);
  //console.log("nb line last12: " + last12hArr.length);
  var nbMinVNIVent24h = (interval * last24hArr.length)/60;
  var nbMinVNIVent12h = (interval * last12hArr.length)/60;
  if (nbMinVNIVent24h >= 960){
    aGLLD1219Detected.push({date : formatDate(d1), code :'GLLD012'});
    break; // 1 act is enough we break
  } else if (nbMinVNIVent12h >= 120) {
    aGLLD1219Detected.push({date : formatDate(d1), code : 'GLLD019'});
    break;
  }
  tmp.push({datetime:d1, nbMinVNIVent24h:nbMinVNIVent24h, nbMinVNIVent12h:nbMinVNIVent12h
  });
}

console.log(tmp);
console.log("actes glld01219 detected");
console.log(aGLLD1219Detected);
// if Both GLLD012-19 then 12 


// For days in NON INV days 

// GROUP per day and detect GLLD012 if nbMinVNIVent24h >= 960min
// else if nbMinVNIVent12h >= 120 detect GLLD019

function formatDate(date) {
  return ((d) => d.getFullYear() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getDate())(new Date(date));
}

// I want to know the number of minutes the patient has been ventilated per 24h & per 12h
const output = [
{ "datetime" : "2014/11/01", nbMinutesVNIVent24h: 10, nbMinutesVNIVent12h:6},
{ "datetime" : "2014/11/03", nbMinutesVNIVent24h: 1, nbMinutesVNIVent12h:1}  
];
```

Comment: I am thinking about doing another question more simple, just with the part where I need to group by seconds. Please if you see another way of doing that don't hesitate

Comment: I solved the first part of the question, I am retrieving now the interval https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54578011/do-the-same-than-this-sql-query-but-in-javascript